# showing custom dialog fragment when a button in a recycle view within a fragment is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have buttons in my recycle view list which is in a fragment. I want to have a pop up (with the custom layout) when the button is clicked.

Thus, I have declared setOnClickListener in my recycle view adapter. When the button is clicked, the function below will be called:

```
    public void showPopup() {

    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new bookingpopdialog();

    dialogFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "OpenPopup");


}
```

There isn't any error during building. However, when I clicked the button on my phone, an error occurs saying that

```
android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Comment: what type of `mContext` is this. Is this a application context or getActivity()?

Comment: its the activity's context which was parsed into the recycleview adapter during the generation of the recycleview list. Basically it is the context of the activity which contain the fragment

Comment: Your error clearly shows that you are trying to cast your application into FragmentActivity any only here `((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager()` you are casting. So please confirm your recyclerview context which loks like application context. Either your passing context or accepted context in recyclerview constructor may be of application type.

Comment: the recycleview content i passed in is the "getActivity.getApplicationContext". Are you saying that there are different kind of context and i might have used the wrong one?

Comment: `getActivity.getApplicationContext` in place of this just use `getActivity()`.

Comment: it works! thanks. can you explain whats the difference between these 2. Sorry, i am new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may put in your adapter class before onCreate method the next declaration

```
protected View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
```

Then in the adapter class in the methods, put the setOnItemClickListener method

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
}
```

In the mainclass or wherever you have the adapter to fill the recyclerView take the adapter's variable and do like this

```
// DispositivosAdapter its my adapter variable
    DispositivosAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // devicesList is an Arraylist
            // recyclerView its the name of my recycler in my xml document
            // .getName() its a method from my class Devices
            String device = devicesList.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getName();

            Snackbar.make(v, "Hi I'm " + device, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```